# Port 9050 Not Listening tb selenium

Tags: python, selenium, tor

I want to use the tbselenium package for browser automation on a linux mint machine.
When I try to run a code that should work python gives me the error message:

```
tbselenium.exceptions.TBDriverPortError: SOCKS port 9050 is not listening
```

The code im trying to use is :

```
from tbselenium.tbdriver import TorBrowserDriver
import time
with TorBrowserDriver("/home/sas/Videos/tor-browser_en-US/") as driver:
    driver.get("https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver")
```

Does anyone have any idea why thats a thing ?
Answers apreaciated  :)

EDIT:
My only open Port is 5060

Comment: Tor browser uses port 9150.

Comment: why does it give me that error then?

Comment: `tor` is actually 2 things: (1) the firefox frontend browser that renders web pages and (2) the `tor.exe`, which runs like a proxy server on your machine and does the network connection stuff below the hood. I couldn't get the samples from `tbselenium` running and kept getting errors until I (A) changed `tor` and `firefox` to `tor.exe` and `firefox.exe` in `common.py` @ the line `DEFAULT_TBB_FX_BINARY_PATH` ... (B) got `geckodriver.exe` and put it into a `%PATH%` folder and (C) ran `tor.exe` from `[tor installation path]\Browser\TorBrowser\Tor\` (it's a service that runs in the background).

Answer (score 1):

You could try running `apt get install tor`, to download the tor service, then simply run `tor` in terminal to start a proxy on port 9050 (by default).

Now you need to configure your firefox driver to proxy http requests through your tor instance.

```
from selenium import webdriver

fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)

fp.set_preference("network.proxy.http", "127.0.0.1")
fp.set_preference("network.proxy.http_port", 9050)
fp.set_preference("network.proxy.https", "127.0.0.1")
fp.set_preference("network.proxy.https_port", 9050)

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
driver.get("https://google.com")
```

I don't think you will be able to use the `tbselenium` package if you want to do it in this way, but it shouldn't matter.

If you can't get this working let me know what errors you are receiving.

Comment: This does not let you access `.onion` services.

Comment: @Reinstate Monica when you want to browse censored websites (e.g. youtube in my country) you'll see this: "http://s7.picofile.com/file/8383089342/Untitled1.png" can you help?

Comment: @Reinstate Monica I have found sth here but understand nothing: "https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/16554/this-is-a-socks-proxy-not-an-http-proxy"

Comment: @PrsFathollahi Sorry, I'm really not sure what to do.  You should try asking that question on [Tor StackExchange](https://tor.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

When running this "basic usage" example (https://github.com/webfp/tor-browser-selenium), I had the same issue (`SOCKS port 9050 is not listening`):

```
from tbselenium.tbdriver import TorBrowserDriver
with TorBrowserDriver("/path/to/TorBrowserBundle/") as driver:
    driver.get('https://check.torproject.org')
```

The following command fixed the issue:

```sh
sudo service tor restart
```

Answer (score 0):

I passed through the same persistent issue when using `tbselenium` the first time. So I decide to use the alternative usage with `stem` were the same issue pop up to me but pointing to a different port. The problem was that I miss a tiny paragraph in the README of the library (https://github.com/webfp/tor-browser-selenium) where says that you need `pip install stem` to use that alternative. So I did it and after that it worked.